# Tree of arity n: How to call a vertex that has only k (k<n) children?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees

What is the correct adjective for a vertex in an n-ary tree that has only k children (k < n)?

I was thinking of something like "unsaturated", but I don't know if that is the correct word for this.